# List of Analysis Toolpak - VBA functions

Tags: vba, add-in

how can I get the complete list of Analysis Tookpak -VBA functions so that they can be written in VBA codes when the addin is referenced directly in VBA? For example, "histogram" function is referenced like this:

```
'Vba Code
sub atpsub()
histogram Candle_data.Range("L:L"), Sheet1.Cells(1, 3), Sheet1.Range("a1:a12"), False, True, False, True
End Sub
```

Problem is I don't know the names of other ATP fucntions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use the *Object Catalog* (F2) and then select `atpvbaen.xls`

Comment: When `atpvbaen.xlam` add-in is loaded, it creates a new group (`Analysis' in `Data` ribbon tab), which has a dialog named `Data Analysis`. Clicking on that option, you can see another window, keeping an enumeration of all available functions. Double clicking an option, another window allowing to select the involved ranges and make some specific settings will appear.  Clicking OK the function will be inserted...

Comment: you can also use auto-completion: type `VBA_Functions_and_Subs.` - after the dot a list of all available globals will show to pick from

Comment: Thanks. The *Object Catalog (F2)* worked for me. The ribbon method doesn't introduce vba code -- as I understand. The intellisense for `VBA_Functions_and_Subs` doesn't seem to work for me.